# Date is not getting set

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure  that should always set a date, but it does not:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'player_extend_membership` (pid INTEGER, daysToAdd INTEGER, OUT result INTEGER)
BEGIN
SELECT PlayerMembershipEndDate INTO @memDate FROM players WHERE players.PlayerID = pid LIMIT 1;
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO @num;

IF @num = 0 THEN
    SET result = -1;
ELSE

    IF @memDate = NULL OR DATE(@memDate) < DATE(NOW()) THEN
        SET @finalDate = DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL daysToAdd DAY);
    ELSE
        SET @finalDate = DATE_ADD(DATE(@memDate), INTERVAL daysToAdd DAY);
    END IF;

SELECT @finalDate, @memDate;
UPDATE players SET PlayerMembershipEndDate = @finalDate
WHERE players.PlayerID = pid;
SET result = 1;
END IF;
END
```

When I check the return value, it is 1, therefore the account does exist. It tells me the result of the select query is always that @finalDate is NULL.

However, if ake it out of the IF and just do:

```
SET @finalDate = DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL daysToAdd DAY);
```

The date is set correctly.

I'm not sire what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `row_count()` isn't used with `select`.  What is the logic you are trying to implement?

Comment: have you tried setting @memDate differently? as in `SET @memDate := (SELECT PlayerMembershipEndDate FROM players WHERE players.PlayerID = pid LIMIT 1);`  and whats the row_count() for?

Comment: memDate is NULL, but either way, we have an if, else block, and at least one should be setting @finalDate

Comment: your out result is always set to 1 so it will reach that every time assuming your sql is correct... if an update doesn't make any changes it'll still hit the result = 1 line

Comment: @Milo i don't think its gitting to the `@finalDate`.. i think row_count = 0 so it escapes that whole else.. then does an insert and sets it to 1

Comment: Nope, it was the = NULL, should be IS NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure seems way too complicated.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
set @result = -1;
UPDATE players
    SET PlayerMembershipEndDate = (case when (@result := 1) is null then NULL
                                        when @memDate IS NULL OR DATE(@memDate) < DATE(NOW())
                                        then DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL daysToAdd DAY)
                                        else DATE_ADD(DATE(@memDate), INTERVAL daysToAdd DAY)
                                   end)
    WHERE players.PlayerID = pid;
```

The first condition in the `case` just sets `@result` if a row is found.  I've left your formulation of `DATE(NOW())` even though `CURDATE()` is more succinct.

I suspect the actual problem with your logic was the `= NULL`.  This always returns "UNKNOWN", which is treated as false.  The correct expression is `is NULL`.

Comment: @memDate is PlayerMembershipEndDate